# How to call a ViewController.m method from the AppDelegate.m

Tags: objective-c, viewcontroller, appdelegate

In my ViewController.m I have my void "Save Data":

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController
@synthesize myDatePicker, myTextField;

-(void)saveData
{
NSArray *value = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:[myTextField text],[myDatePicker date], nil];
[value writeToFile:[self getFilePath] atomically:YES];

}
```

And I want to use my void "Save Data" in my AppDelegate.m :

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{

[self.ViewController saveData];

}
```

But Xcode doesn't recognize the "ViewController" neither "saveData".

I don't know if I have to #import something in my AppDelegate, please help.

Comment: The current answer is correct - have your view controller observe the notification you want to handle. But your call is unconventional. Do you have a property to reference the view controller whose method you are trying to call. the compiler errors are telling you that they have not been correctly set up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How you access your viewcontroller from the app delegate will depend on how many viewcontrollers you have / where it is in your current navigation hierarchy, etc etc. You could add a property for it, or perhaps it will be your app delegate's `rootViewController`.

However, you'd probably be better off listening out for a notification in your viewcontroller when the app enters the background. This means that the logic you need can be entirely self contained within your viewcontroller, and your app delegate doesn't need to know anything about it.

In your viewcontroller's initialization method, you can register to receive notifications:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(applicationDidEnterBackground:)
                                             name:UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification
                                           object:nil];
```

Then, implement the method:

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    [self saveData];
}
```

And make sure you also remove yourself as an observer in your viewcontroller's `dealloc` method:

```
-(void)dealloc 
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification object:nil];
}
```

Comment: I did as you said, but I got a problem when I close the application, once I want to open it again it crashes and doesn't open. I don't know what's going on there.  (( There should be a * after the NSNotification in the void right? ))

Comment: Yes, there should be a *, have updated my answer. What error message are you getting when it crashes? What line does it break on?

Comment: There isn't an error message. Once I have installed the app in the iOS Simulator running iOS 7, with xCode closed and relaunching the Simulator, it works for the first time, but when I close and open again the app expecting to see what I "saved" the app just doesn't open. Just that..

Answer (score 0):

In your "appDelegate.m" implementation file at the top do this import  ->

```
#import "ViewController.h"
```

This will make the custom class ViewController visible to the appDelegate.

In order to be able to call the -(void)saveData method from another class (in our case the other class is the AppDelegate class), this method needs to be declared in the public interface. That means ->

```
#import "ViewController.h"


@interface ViewController ()

-(void)saveData;

@end
```

Comment: I did the #import as you said, but I still can not add the `[self.viewController saveData]` in my AppDelegate.m because Xcode doesn't recognize the viewController neither the "saveData" again.

Comment: self.ViewController implies that you created a property on appDelegate called ViewController. First problem is, that it starts with UpperCase. Please rename it to viewController. 
The other thing is, do you actually have a proper instance of that viewController? Perhaps this property is not initialised. Do you understand the concept of instances? I need to ask even if it might sound silly (sorry :)), otherwise I am not sure how deep is you understanding.

Comment: But proper "instance" sounds new to me. You might give me a hand on that.

Comment: What you posted is the ViewController class interface. I need to see the AppDelegate.h interface.